# Serialization of BigInteger fields as String (in plain notation) using Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, biginteger

Is there any way to serialize BigInteger field in plain format as String JavaScript object field, rather than Numeric in exponential notation (which is default behavior of Jackson)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a specific serializer defined with JsonSerialize annotation

https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonSerialize.html

The problem is similar to this question:

[Java to Jackson JSON serialization: Money fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11319445/java-to-jackson-json-serialization-money-fields)

Comment: This solution is good in case you know the property type in compile time. In my case, I have a generic class that in some cases, one of its properties might be a BigInt and I want it to be serialized as a string. My question is, how do I replace the default BigInt serializer with one of my own? (the generic type might be a List<BigInt> for example)

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is the way:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ToStringSerializer;
...
@JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
final private BigInteger serviceFee;
```