# Prevent Jackson from serializing a float as a double

Tags: java, floating-point, jackson

Jackson seems to be coercing all floats into doubles in any data structure that I am trying to serialize into JSON. Is there any way to avoid this behavior?

```
Float f = 50.1f;
System.out.println(f);                                 // 50.1
System.out.println(f.doubleValue());                   // 50.099998474121094
System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().valueToTree(f)); // 50.099998474121094 -- how to prevent this?
```

Using jackson-all-1.9.11.jar.

Comment: By the way, why Jackson 1.9.x? The current version is 2.2.x...

Comment: Did you try using [FloatSerializer](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/std/NumberSerializers.FloatSerializer.html) ?

Comment: @fge Working within a massive codebase. Can't easily upgrade.

Comment: @TheNewIdiot Thanks. That will definitely work, as will new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(), apparently.

Comment: Could you use BigDecimal instead of Float?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the custom Jackson serializer of your own  as described in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11319445/java-to-jackson-json-serialization-money-fields)

[Java to Jackson JSON serialization: Money fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11319445/java-to-jackson-json-serialization-money-fields)