# Transmit BigDecimal type in Spring Restful

Tags: java, spring, bigdecimal

This is a method in my spring Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = AccountLvlConfigURI.GET_CONFIG_AGENCY, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public 
@ResponseBody AccLvlConfigRes getAccountLevelConfigByAgency() throws BusinessException {
    return accountLevelConfigBo.getAccountLevelConfigByAgency();
}
```

And here is my AccLvlConfigRes class:

```
public class AccLvlConfigRes implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2066756616998244103L;

    private Integer levelNumber;
    private Integer minPoint;
    private BigDecimal percentBuyTicketInter;

    public AccLvlConfigRes(){}

    // Getters - Setters

}
```

The problem is the client can get values of levelNumber, minPoint, however, can't get value of percentBuyTicketInter (5 scale, 2 precision).

How can I transmit the BigDecimal variable type to client in Spring Restful

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java to Jackson JSON serialization: Money fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11319445/java-to-jackson-json-serialization-money-fields)

Comment: Follow the link, I think it will get you where you want to go.  You need to write a custom serializer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. solution i did was to to declare percentBuyTicketInter as a string and in the setter covert it to bigdecimal. It worked for us.