# Use @ResponseBody Return BigDecimal Precision Lost

Tags: spring, bigdecimal

In my project, I use Spring `@ResponseBody` and When I return a Object contains `BigDecimal` like that :

```
{
  "messageType" : "",
  "messageContent" : "",
  "valueObj" : 100.00,
  "redirectUrl" : "",
  "success" : false
}
```

then, the response body in browser is

```
{
  "messageType" : "",
  "messageContent" : "",
  "valueObj" : 100,
  "redirectUrl" : "",
  "success" : false
}
```

I have a problem with BigDecimal Precision loosing. 
its precision ***(100.00 --> 100)***.

What is the problem with Spring to convert BigDecimal. Would you please provide me the solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11319445/java-to-jackson-json-serialization-money-fields

Comment: thank you @R.G,  i think the link's description is current reason of my asked question. i will have a try.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the precision is not lost in your example. `100.00` is the same as `100` as the value is written as a number and not a String. If the value would be serialized as a String `"valueObj" : "100"` you could argue that it is a difference but not for a number.

You would have a problem if e.g. `100.01` is shorten to `100`, but is this also the case?