# Jackson: why doesn't annotating BigDecimal fields with @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING) work?

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I have the following class that has to be serialized:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class CampaignCurrentData {
    private static final int FRAC_SPENT_SCALE = 6;

    //TBD: transfer campaign ID to long in proto and here
    private Long campaignId;
    private Long budgetId;
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    private BigDecimal amountSpent;
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    private BigDecimal dailyBudget;
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    private BigDecimal fracSpent;
    private Set<String> countriesSet;
    private boolean isCampaignCbs;
}
```

Since it contains BigDecimal fields, I added the annotation

```
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work and I still get the error:

> ###UncheckedExecutionException:
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: N/A  at [Source:
> (byte[])"{"campaignIdToFactorComputationData":{"1032633420":{"pacingFactor":0.001,"pidError":-0.6111111111111112,"pidIntegral":0.001,"selectedCountryCode":"IL","targetCappingHourExcluded":18,"startingHourIncluded":0,"selectedMarketHistoryDataForCampaign":{"countryCode":"IL","hourToExpectedEngagePaidListings":{"1
> 0":10.0,"0 0":10.0,"23 0":10.0,"22 0":10.0,"21 0":10.0,"20 0":10.0,"19
> 0":10.0,"18 0":10.0,"17 0":10.0,"16 0":10.0,"15 0":10.0,"14
> 0":10.0,"13 0":10.0,"12 0":10.0,"11 0":10.0,"10 0":10.0,"9
> 0":10"[truncated 528 bytes]; line: 1, column: 934] (through reference
> chain:
> ###BudgetPacerCycleOutput["campaignIdToCurrentData"]->java.util.LinkedHashMap["1032633420"]->###.CampaignCurrentData["amountSpent"])

I tried to replace the annotations

@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)

with

@JsonIgnore

and I didn't get the error.
However, I don't want to ignore these fields.
What can I do?

Comment: what r u trying to do here?

Comment: pass this object to another service

Comment: Does this answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11319445/java-to-jackson-json-serialization-money-fields

Comment: Do you want to serialise this class to `JSON` payload or deserialise `JSON` payload to this class? Which version of `Jackson` do you use?

Comment: @MichałZiober
2.10.1

Comment: Could you please create and share simple test how do you use this class and `Jackson`. It should work properly.