# It is spring or the web server change the precision of the bigdecimal field of the api?

Tags: java, spring

I was build my api based on springmvc v4.3.12, weblogic12c, there is one api will return a big number, its a BigDecimal field, maybe its because the number is too big that make this strange things happend.

code:

```
@GetMapping(value = "test")
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, BigDecimal>> test() throws IOException {
    Map<String, BigDecimal> map = Maps.newHashMap();
    map.put("a", new BigDecimal("555511112222333.1729").setScale(4, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN));
    return ResponseEntity.ok(map);
}
```

output:

```
{
  "a": 555511112222333.2
}
```

if change the number to 5555111122223.1729, the output will be 5555111122223.173

if change the number to 555511.1729, the output will be 555511.1729

I have debugged the code of spring, it was wrote the number into servlet response buffer correctly, but in the caller side, like swagger ui, the number was lost precisions.

I also tried with springboot v2.3.2, the api returned Bigdecimal field correctly, did't lost precisions.

Comment: Jackson, by default, is used to send JSON. So probably Jackson is using some default precision/length for those numbers. It could even be the `tostring` of `BigDecimal` is being used as you are serializing a `Map` instead of an object.

Comment: Be aware the limit of javascript number too ... It's often shorter than java long/bigdecimal

Comment: JSON by default uses `double` for decimal numbers (since this is what all programming languages understand) and this is what Jackson upon serializing a `BigDecimal` does by default. There are ways to tell Jackson to use custom serializers (https://stackoverflow.com/a/18226861) but then you will get `"a": "5555111122223.1729"`

Comment: @ThomasKläger there are many people give the answer just like you said change the number to string, and they are choose to ignore the difference between a number and a string, it is not find out the root cause, just skip it.

Answer (score 0):

I did some further research.

I used this small program to verify what output the backend produces:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class JsonOutput {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        Map<String, BigDecimal> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("a", new BigDecimal("555511112222333.17291234567890"));

        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(om.writeValueAsString(map));
    }
}
```

And this prints

```
{"a":555511112222333.17291234567890}
```

So the backend produces the output that you want. This conclusion is supported by the following statement from your question:

> I have debugged the code of spring, it was wrote the number into servlet response buffer correctly

Therefore I re-read the second part of your statement:

> but in the caller side, like swagger ui, the number was lost precisions

And in the end this makes totally sense:

The Swagger UI is a generic UI and doesn't know anything about your formatting needs. It probably just uses [`JSON.parse()`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/structured-data.html#sec-json.parse) to read the JSON that your code generated. And `JSON.parse()` interprets any number value as [`ECMAScript Number`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-data-types-and-values.html#sec-ecmascript-language-types-number-type) which for most purposes is basically the same as a Java `double` value.

And therefore my conclusion from the comment still holds:

- If your backend code needs to control the representation of a numeric value it must not transmit it as numeric value but as a string
- If your backend code transmits a numeric value as a numeric value then whoever reads that value will apply its formatting rules to the value
- If you are in full control of backend **and** frontend you can do as you wish

Comment: It is a bug of spring, or jackson, and i find out a solusion is that change the response content to json string then write it into servlet response.