# How to keep zeros after decimal for BigDecimal in Java Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, bigdecimal

I have some `BigDecimal` values in database, like 10000.00, 12357.87 etc.

Now I'm trying to get these values by using GET API REST in spring boot, but here the problem is
in Swagger or Postman response I see like:

```
"amount":"10000.00"
```

but I want value without quotes "amount": 10000.00

Response class:

```
public class ResponseDTO{
  @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
  private BigDecimal amount;
}
```

If I removed `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)` annotation it will shown as `"amount":10000`

Comment: So when you say 'keep zeroes after decimal point' you really mean 'remove quotation marks'? And do you realize that 10000 and 10000.00 are the same value?

Comment: @user207421 i don't want remove the zeros, i need zeros in response

Answer (score 0):

You can set "scale" value of amount as 2.

Try something like this;

instead of `responsedto.setAmount(amount)` use `responsedto.setAmount(amount.setScale(2))`

With this you don't need to use @JsonFormat annotation.

Comment: tried but **.00** not showing in response **.87** or **.01** like this values coming in response

Comment: Are you sure that you need to see .00 instead of .87? Maybe you can round the number. with amount.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP) somethingk like this.  see this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html

Comment: only .00 or .0 values not coming other values coming.

Comment: It is missing while coming to response

Comment: For your problem this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65083720/5802053 is the way to go

Comment: @Valentyn i tried this **@JsonSerialize(using = MoneySerializer.class)** also but it will return values in string format like **"amount":"10000.00"** but i don't want quotes

Comment: @Durga As you need your number written as number (not as string) you should write your custom serialiser as in link I've posted or use https://github.com/zalando/jackson-datatype-money module

Comment: @Valentyn 12357.87 value is coming fine but here only problem with 10000.00, if zeros is there after decimal point then only we are not getting in response

Comment: @Valentyn custom serialiser also giving values in string format.

Comment: @Durga - if you use `writeNumber` in it then either your serializer is not invoked or something replaces its result - check with debugger that serializer is invoked. Jackson `writeNumber` writes input as number, there is no way for it to do something else

Comment: @Valentyn writeNumber giving like **"amount":10000** only, not giving decimals

Comment: @Durga
Here is complete working example:
https://github.com/valb3r/flyway_9_spring_2_7_2-issue/tree/jackson
If you invoke DummyController with `curl "localhost:8080/dummies/"` you will get `[{"id":1,"amount":10.12},{"id":2,"amount":12.12},{"id":3,"amount":13.00},{"id":4,"amount":14.00},{"id":5,"amount":15.00}]` just as expected. In your case you need to check your Jackson configuration and that the **custom serialiser** is really invoked

Comment: @Valentyn i was implemented as same ae your logic but i'm not getting, i am checking response for my api in swagger, may be swagger will block anything?

Comment: @Durga No, swagger is just an UI wrapper above your API, it should not cause the effect (however it is implementation dependent so you can check API with i.e. `curl` just to be 100% sure). Have you checked with the debugger that `custom serializer` is really invoked? 
Typical cases for the behaviour you observe:
 - Misconfigured ObjectMapper, so that serializer is invoked
 - Multiple ObjectMappers used in project causing the annotation not to be found due to i.e. different API versions (I.e. accidental import from shaded jar)